# How to create WebSocket in React-Native correctly, It gets created multiple time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to make a chat application with django-channels and react-native

but I don't know how to create the WebSocket
I tried this:

```
const ChatScreen=({navigation, route})=> {
   room = route.params.item
   const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
       `ws://192.168.1.14:8000/ws/chat/${room.name}/`,
   );
   const sendMsg=()=>{
       chatSocket.send(
           JSON.stringify({
               message,
               room: room.id,
               owner: 1
           }
   const getMsgs=()=>{
        apiServer.get(`/chat/api/rooms/${room.id}`)
               .then((resp)=>setChat(resp.data)
               .catch((e)=>console.log(e)
   };
   chatSocket.onmessage = () => getMsgs()
.
.
.
       <TouchableOpacity 
           onPress={async()=>{
               await sendMsg()
               setMessage('')
           }>. . .</ToucableOpacity>
```

but it ended up creating new WebSocket every time my app re-renders
and messages sent multiple time
So I tried this

```
const [chatSocket, setSocket] = setState({})
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket(
      `ws://192.168.1.14:8000/ws/chat/${room.name}/`,
    );
    setSocket(socket);
}
```

It worked but every time I rejoined the room it started a new websocket without closing the old one.
So I tried to add an event listener to remove it

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getMessages();
    const socket = new WebSocket(
      `ws://192.168.1.14:8000/ws/chat/${room.name}/`,
    );
    setSocket(socket);

    

    const closeSocket = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', () => {
        chatSocket.close();
    });
    return closeSocket;
  }, [navigation]);
```

I ended up with this error `TypeError: chatSocket.close is not a function`

So how to close the websocket after leaving the room or how to set this correctly

This is my consumers.py file:

```
User = get_user_model()


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_message(self, owner, msg, room):
        print(owner, ' - ', msg, ' - ', room)
        room = Room.objects.get(pk=room)
        owner = User.objects.get(pk=1)
        new_msg = Message.objects.create(owner=owner, content=msg, room=room)
        new_msg.save()
        return new_msg

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Recive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = data_json['message']
        owner = data_json['owner']
        room = data_json['room']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'owner': owner,
                'room': room
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        owner = event['owner']
        room = event['room']
        new_msg = await self.create_message(owner, message, room)

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send('msg sent')
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error: `TypeError: chatSocket.close is not a function` because you're trying to call `close` on the return value of `navigation.addListener`, which is actually a function and it doesn't contain the property `close`.

Your `useEffect` callback isn't implemented correctly, specifically these lines:

```
const closeSocket = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', () => {
  chatSocket.close();
});
return closeSocket;
```

So the correct implementation would be something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getMessages();
  const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://192.168.1.14:8000/ws/chat/${room.name}/`);
  setSocket(socket);

  const unsubscribeListener = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', () => {
    socket.close();
  });
  return unsubscribeListener;
}, [navigation]);
```

If you don't have a good reason to use the `beforeRemove` listener from `React Navigation`, I would also suggest you to just use the cleanup function from `useEffect`, since it's getting called when your component unmounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getMessages();
  const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://192.168.1.14:8000/ws/chat/${room.name}/`);
  setSocket(socket);

  return () => {
    // socket.close() will be called when the component unmounts
    // that is when you go back from this screen
    socket.close();
  };
}, []);
```